# JSF 2.2 internationalization

Tags: java, internationalization, jsf-2.2

I have tried [MKyiong's](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/) and [javacodegeeks's](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jsf/jsf-internationalization-example/)  good guides - everything is working fine.

I have a template that contains navigation bar, contact info stored in WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml.
In this template I have a block containing

```
<div id="content">
 <ui:insert name="content">
   [Template content will be inserted here]
 </ui:insert>
```

In my file `WEB-INF/langTest.xhtml` I try

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">     <h:form>

    <h2><h:outputText value="#{msg['welcome.jsf']}" /></h2>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        Language : 
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{language.localeCode}" onchange="submit()"
            valueChangeListener="#{language.countryLocaleCodeChanged}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{language.countriesInMap}" /> 
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
      </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

When I run the project, visually everything is working, template is OK.
If I change my Firefox=>Preferences=>Content=>Languages settings everything is displayed in that language
BUT 
If I want to change it by selecting other language from the dropdown menu 
all the parts `#{msg['welcome.jsf']}` does NOT change, they display the language that is defined in the browser properties.

I have put a this `#{language.language}` in my `WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml`
And it showing me that the Managed bean is accepting my language selection from the dropdown, but no effect on the `#{msg['welcome.jsf']}`

I think that I'm missing

```
<html lang="#{localeBean.language}"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"><f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}">...</f:view></html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Stupid mistake there at Mkyong. Read the comments on bottom of page, they were already indicative and contained the actual answer. In any case, this question has already been asked and answered here before.

Comment: Javacodegeeks seems to be another Internet copypaste/seed machine which is trying to earn something with ads. Just ignore that site forever.